# How do I give a role when someone boosts in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I know that discord already auto roles boosters but I am trying to make it so when someone boost 2x it gives them another role and if they boost 3x they get another role?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [on_member_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_member_update) event and the [Member.add_roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) method

Comment: can you you put the code because i have not heard of this message